# A Queue of deques in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to have a data structure conformed by a list of deques. So, taking advantage of the FIFO disposition of elements in a queue, I instantiated the following:

```
Deque<String> pathQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

and also,

```
Queue<Deque<String>> myQueueOfDeques = new LinkedList<Deque<String>>();
```

However when I add each deque and print `myQueueOfDeques`, it appears with the correct size of empty fields, e.g. when it is supposed to store three deques it shows `[ [], [], [] ]`. Here is the portion of the code.

```
for (Element leaf; (leaf = (Element)walker.nextNode()) != null; ) {
            for (Node node = leaf; node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE; node = node.getParentNode())
            {
                pathQueue.addFirst(((Element)node).getAttribute("id"));
            }
            myQueueOfDeques.add(pathQueue);
            pathQueue.clear();
        }
 System.out.println(myQueueOfDeques);
```

Clearly the problem is that I keep thinking it as the way data structures work in c++, however I know this is java and I'm having a hard time. I already read the documentation for different structures found here

Comment: Java objects are references. You're adding a reference to `pathQueue` to `myQueueOfDeques`, then clearing it. Allocate a new `pathQueue` at the beginning of each iteration.

Comment: But I need to remove all the elements of `pathQueue` each time the deepest bucle finishes.

Comment: No, you don't. `pathQueue` is a _reference_ to an object. `myQueueOfDeques.add(pathQueue);` adds a reference to the object pointed to by `pathQueue` to the list pointed to by `myQueueOfDeques`. If you clear the object pointed to by `pathQueue`, it also clears the object that you just added to `myQueueOfDeques`, because they're the _same thing_.

Comment: Think of what would happen in C++ if `pathQueue` was a pointer and you had a list of pointers. Speaking of which, you should probably use another `ArrayDeque` as a queue because it also implements that interface and usually faster than `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand one important thing: in Java, everything is a reference and references behave somewhat like pointers in C++. So when you add a deque to the queue, you don't add a copy, but rather the very queue you've just filled up. This is, of course, very good performance-wise, but you end up with `pathQueue` being not just identical to what you have in your min queue, but the *very same queue.* Then you clear it and of course it's now empty. How to deal with that? Obviously by creating a new queue each time. Allocation is pretty cheap in Java, unlike C++, so you should really prefer it to reusing the same object over and over in most cases.

Given that, your code should probably look like this:

```
for (Element leaf; (leaf = (Element)walker.nextNode()) != null; ) {
    Deque<String> pathQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    for (Node node = leaf; node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE; node = node.getParentNode())
    {
        pathQueue.addFirst(((Element)node).getAttribute("id"));
    }
    myQueueOfDeques.add(pathQueue);
}
System.out.println(myQueueOfDeques);
```

And as I've mentioned, you should probably use `ArrayDeque` as a queue. It's usually more efficient in both time and memory than a `LinkedList`. In fact, I believe that about the only time when you really want to use a `LinkedList` is when you want fast insertions and removals in the middle. Otherwise, `ArrayDeque` is usually better both for queues and stacks (there is a class called `Stack` but it's considered obsolete, so when looking for stacks, look for anything that implements the `Deque` interface).

So you should really change your main queue declaration to this:

```
Queue<Deque<String>> myQueueOfDeques = new ArrayDeque<Deque<String>>();
```